# basic doubts about asp.net mvc 4 and wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

Well, I am thinking about creating a web application with C# and asp.net mvc 4. The idea is create an asp.net web application that can be use in any browser, so I can use my application anywhere and any computer.

But in the communication, can I use WCF or the communication is over HTTP and I can't choose other transport?

I mean that if WCF is only to communicate two desktop/mobile applications or it could be use for web applications too?

In a web application is possible to have a duplex communication?

Comment: why the `asp.net-mvc-3` tag if you want to use `asp.net-mvc-4`?

Comment: well, really I didn't find the tag mvc4

Comment: I'm not sure that it makes sense to use duplex communication to a browser.

Comment: And how could I notify some error to the client for example when I try to update the stock of an item, if I try to subtract more intems that there are avaliable?

Comment: Or other example, how to notify why I have a new message, like facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTTP bindings in WCF if you want to use SOAP. Otherwise you may want to look into [WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api) which provides a more natural abstraction over HTTP. For duplex communication over HTTP you can consider [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

Comment: and if I want transfer file to the server to store it in the database, is more efficient TCP than HTTP? it would be possible to use other protocols in a web application or I can only use HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

> can I use WCF

**Yes**, WCF can be hosted in an asp.net application.

Comment: and How does it works? I mean that if the client that access to my web site eith the browser and wnat to do some query to the  database, does the request got trough the WCF service? How know the browser how the contract is?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía, it depends on the URL you're requesting, if it's a WCF URL it goes in the WCF pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

**Duplex Communication cant induced easily in Client-server model where system is working in disconnected fashion.**

What happen when when your client(browser) want some data.
1) Request comes to server
2) Server ask to WCF duplex service and forgot to wait for response as it is duplex in nature.
3) WCF duplex respond to Server with data
4) Now server can process that data either by saving or logging to Database but doesn't know who was the client that asked for and how to intimate them.

So what is the solution
User `SignalR` with Some weird coding.

OR

*Call WCF service directly from Browser by jquery `$.ajax` call So your browser directly will have response from WCF service.*